# Is there an equivalent to copernic pro desktop search engine available for mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, software, search, search-engine

Is there an equivalent  to copernic pro desktop search engine available for mac? I mean something serious not spotlight or found! Something that is able to search terabytes of data and index millions of keywords and search *inside* pdfs and all sorts of data. I have searched and so far haven't found anything as good as copernic pro for mac.

Comment: p.s more than happy to pay for it!

Answer (score 1):

Two that come to mind are :

EasyFind -- which is in the Mac App store

and

Docfetcher which is a java application

http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html